# Are the Tuples in Swift complete alternative to Anonymous types as in C#

Tags: c#, ios, swift, ios8

Like [Anonymous Types in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). Are the Tuples in the newly launched language Swift can do what Anonymous types in C# can do?

While learning swift, I found a few statements (They call it Tuples) like

```
let http200Status = (statusCode: 200, description: "OK")
```

And we can access them in way like

```
println("The status code is \(http200Status.statusCode)")
// prints "The status code is 200"
println("The status message is \(http200Status.description)")
// prints "The status message is OK”
```

It feels exactly like Anonymous types in C#.

Is Tuple in Swift complete alternative to anonymous types in C#? Can someone give me a comparison of Tuples and Anonymous types? What I can do in one and cannot do in other. I found one thing so far that in C#, we cannot return Anonymous types (unless as object) but we can do it in Swift.

Comment: Tuple is an immutable collection object. Anonymous type is a way to instantiate object. those are 2 different subjects.

Comment: @Franck Tuples are not strictly immutable in Swift, it depends on `let` vs `var`.

Answer (score 2):

Tuples in Swift are somewhat a hybrid between C#'s anonymous types and generic `Tuple<T1, T2, ...>` classes.

As with C# anonymous types, Swift allows you to name the "properties" of the Tuple if you wish (however, it is only optional):

`let result = (errorCode: 9001, message:"Power level too high!")`

It also allows you to extract certain values while ignoring others when retrieving them:

`let (errorCodeOnly, _) = result`

It is important to note that Swift tuples' immutability is determined by `var` vs `let`.

```
let immutableCard = (suit: "Spades", rank: "Ace")
var mutableCard = (suit: "Hearts", rank: "Queen")

immutableCard.rank = "Jack"    // error, cannot set
mutableCard.rank = "Two"       // OK
```