# Anonymous class in swift

Tags: swift, anonymous-class

Is there an equivalent syntax or technique for Anonymous class in Swift?
Just for clarification Anonymous class in Java example here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Anonymous classes is one of my favorite Java features, so I'm hoping we have them in Swift eventually.

Comment: @hpique True, they are good in Java but they are not really needed in languages which have closures and classes that can be declared inside methods. All that listener/adapter patterns in Java could be implemented easily using closures, without anonymous classes.

Comment: @Sulthan Certainly, you can do a lot with closures and inner classes. But with the extensive use of protocols in Swift I think anonymous classes could be really handy in some situations.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no equivalent syntax, as far as I know.

Regarding equivalent techniques, theoretically you could use closures and define structs and classes inside them. Sadly, I can't get this to work in a playground or project without making it crash. Most likely this isn't ready to be used in the current beta.

Something like...

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func hello()
}

let closure : () -> () = {
    class NotSoAnonymousClass : SomeProtocol {
        func hello() {
            println("Hello")
        }
    }
    let object = NotSoAnonymousClass()
    object.hello()
}
```

...currently outputs this error:

```
invalid linkage type for global declaration
%swift.full_heapmetadata* @_TMdCFIv4Test7closureFT_T_iU_FT_T_L_19NotSoAnonymousClass
LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Since Swift doesn't have anonymous classes, I would use a [named tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102692/975097) here.

Comment: Is there actually any reason we do this workaround? Creating a class in file would look way prettier than this.

Answer (score 14):

You can also create a basic empty class that acts like a bare protocol, and pass a closure to the `init` function that overrides anything you want, like this:

```
class EmptyClass {

    var someFunc: () -> () = { }

    init(overrides: EmptyClass -> EmptyClass) {
        overrides(self)
    }
}

// Now you initialize 'EmptyClass' with a closure that sets
// whatever variable properties you want to override:

let workingClass = EmptyClass { ec in
    ec.someFunc = { println("It worked!") }
    return ec
}

workingClass.someFunc()  // Outputs: "It worked!"
```

It is not technically 'anonymous' but it works the same way. You are given an empty shell of a class, and then you fill it in or override whatever parameters you want when you initialize it with a closure.

It's basically the same, except instead of fulfilling the expectations of a protocol, it is overriding the properties of a class.

Comment: Honestly, this looks ugly. Class that accepts itself as init closure param?

Answer (score 10):

For example, Java listener/adapter pattern would be translated to Swift like this:

```
protocol EventListener {
    func handleEvent(event: Int) -> ()
}

class Adapter : EventListener {
    func handleEvent(event: Int) -> () {
    }
}

var instance: EventListener = {
    class NotSoAnonymous : Adapter {
        override func handleEvent(event: Int) {
            println("Event: \(event)")
        }
    }

    return NotSoAnonymous()
}()

instance.handleEvent(10)
```

(Crashing the compiler on Beta 2)

The problem is, you always have to specify a name. I don't think Apple will ever introduce anonymous classes (and structs etc.) because it would be pretty difficult to come with a syntax that doesn't collide with the trailing closures.

Also in programming anonymous things are bad. Naming things help readers to understand the code.

Comment: I agree that programming anonymous is bad. I need it for test mocks. Given that there is no good mocking framework at the moment, it is too much pain to subclass each and every mock.

Comment: "anonymous is bad" is not generally true, IMO. It is very useful, for example, in the context of lambdas (or anonymous classes) that are used as callbacks.

Comment: The "anonymous is bad" misses the valid use case of implementing a `protocol` for a one-off.  When coming from languages that support them e.g. javascript, java, scala the value is apparent.

Answer (score 7):

No anonymous class syntax in Swift. But, you can create a class inside a class and class methods:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    class anonymousSwiftClass {
        func add(number1:Int, number2:Int) -> Int {
            return number1+number2;
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        class innerSwiftClass {
            func sub(number1:Int, number2:Int) -> Int {
                return number1-number2;
            }
        }

        var inner = innerSwiftClass();
        println(inner.sub(2, number2: 3));

        var anonymous = anonymousSwiftClass();
        println(anonymous.add(2, number2: 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift is so bizarre at times. On one hand it forces you to put curly brackets around single-line `if` statements and to make switch statements exhaustive, yet at the same time allows you to define an entire class inside the *body* of a method. smh

Comment: @devios1, why is it error-prone to define a class inside of the body of a method? It might be ugly by some people's standards but doing it doesn't lead to coding errors like when not using curly braces for the statements after an "if" test (as we have seen in the real world where incorrect indentation can hide bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing (Observer pattern). You can use closures in a similar way you would use anonymous classes in Java. With obvious limitations of course.

```
class Subject {
   // array of closures
   var observers: [() -> Void] = []

   // @escaping says the closure will be called after the method returns
   func register(observer: @escaping () -> Void) {
       observers.append(observer)
   }

   func triggerEvent() {
       observers.forEach { observer in
            observer()
       }
   }
}

var subj = Subject()
// you can use a trailing closure
subj.register() {
    print("observerd")
}

// or you can assign a closure to a variable so you can maybe use the reference to removeObserver() if you choose to implement that method
var namedObserver: () -> Void = {
    print("named observer")
}
subj.register(observer: namedObserver)

subj.triggerEvent()
// output:
// observerd
// named observer
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is the right idea given the lack of support for _anonymous functions_

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inline a click handler in Java style fashion, first define your closure as a variable in your button class:

```
  var onButtonClick: () -> Void = {}
```

Then add a method to accept the closure as parameter and store it in the variable for later use:

```
func onClick(label: String, buttonClickHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
   button.label = label 
   onButtonClick = buttonClickHandler
}
```

Whenever the closure should be executed, call it in your button class:

```
onButtonClick()
```

And this is how to set the action that should occur on click:

```
newButton.onClick(label: "My button") { () in
    print("button clicked")
}
```

You can also accept multiple parameters. For example, a toggle button may be handled like this:

```
var buttonClicked: (_ isOn: Bool) -> Void { set get }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a struct for defining the interface via function values and then anonymously implement it from a function, as is a very common way to write objects in JavaScript.

The function is only required for creating a private scope for the object returned.

```swift
import Foundation

struct Logger {
    let info: (String) -> ()
    let error: (String) -> ()
}

func createSimpleLogger() -> Logger {
    var count = 0
    
    func number() -> Int {
        count += 1
        return count
    }
    
    return Logger(
        info: { message in
            print("INFO - #\(number()) - \(message)")
        },
        error: { message in
            print("ERROR - #\(number()) - \(message)")
        }
    )
}

let logger = createSimpleLogger()

logger.info("Example info log message")
logger.error("Example error log message")
```

Output:

```
INFO - #1 - Example info log message
ERROR - #2 - Example error log message
```