# Interface parameters that are inlined in java with j2objc

Tags: j2objc

I have a method in my Java Model that is called like this:

```
httpClient.login(email, password, new JsonResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, JsonObject response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, JsonObject response) {
        }
    });
```

My question is, how can I use this in Swift after translating my Model to objective-c

```
client.loginWithNSString(email, withNSString: password, withJsonResponseHandler: JsonResponseHandler!)
```

Is there a way to inline the JsonResponseHandler or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of the [Anonymous class in Swift question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408068/anonymous-class-in-swift). It looks like you need to create a class (perhaps inside of a closure) that implements JsonResponseHandler, then create an instance of that class.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the duplicate

Comment: No worries, it was hard to find! :-)